# Discussion kind of question is considered?

Tags: discussion, support

I have some topic which I need to discuss on community, that question is about discussion of pros & cons regarding display templates. Will that be considered as valid question?

Didn't find any specific thing with respect to my question on the web, so I thought before asking the question there I have asked this question here whether it will be valid question to post or not?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Discussion questions shouldn't really be asked as there is no real definitive answer in that case. You should focus on a particular part of the display template that you are wanting to focus on and ask questions off of that. Some examples:

Bad: What are the pros and cons of using display templates?

Good: I'm looking to implement a custom display template for X. I am concerned about Z and am trying to implement using Y. What are the benefits of doing it this way and would I run into any pitfalls.